# Flutter - Container in row/column to fill space but not expand further

Tags: flutter, formatting, expanded

I'm trying to use a Conatiner to create a underline type effect as shown here:

[image: page card title and underline]

However, the Container I'm using isn't visible.

I've tried wrapping wrapping the column in an Exapnded but this then fills all of the horizontal space.

The only thing i've found that works (which is a bit of a dirty hack) is to add a text widget as a child of the container with the same text as the title and this makes it the correct width.  I'm sure there's something obvious but it's totally escaped me.

Thanks in advance.

```
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            // title
            Text(
              title,
              style: baseStyle,
            ),

            // underline
            Container(
              height: 4,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
              ),
              // hacky
              // child: Text(
              //   title,
              //   style: baseStyle,
              // ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, try make this min. not max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your column with `IntrinsicWidth`.

```dart
Row(
  ...,
  children: [
    IntrinsicWidth(
      child: Column(
        children: [...],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width of your container

```
Container(
          height: 4,
          width: 80,   // <---------------------add here
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Unfourtunately I won't know what the width will be - it needs to match the length of the title

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexible Widget to achieve That.

```
return Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        // title
        Flexible(
        flex:1,fit: FlexFit.loose,
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: baseStyle,
        ),

        // underline

        Flexible(
        flex:1,fit: FlexFit.loose,
        child: Container(
          height: 4,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
          ),
          // hacky
          // child: Text(
          //   title,
          //   style: baseStyle,
          // ),
        
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
);}
```

Here the flex property is used to specify the relative proportions of each child widget. And the FlexFit enum is used to determine how a Flexible widget should fit into the available space in its parent Row or Column widget.

The FlexFit enum has two possible values:

```
FlexFit.tight: This value instructs the Flexible widget to fill all the available space in its parent widget. If there is not enough space available, the Flexible widget will overflow its parent widget.

FlexFit.loose: This value instructs the Flexible widget to take up only the minimum space required to accommodate its child widget. If there is extra space available, the Flexible widget will leave it empty.
```

N:B Now play with the Flexible widget to get the perfect output.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work - the example above ran into the same problems i had (not visible) and if the flexible was moved around the column then it filled the full width again

Answer (score 0):

just add some width for your Container
and you can use Divider widget

Comment: Unfourtunately I won't know what the width will be - it needs to match the length of the title

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).